# changing image colour by CSS3 (Filters)

Tags: filter, css, imagefilter

I have a png image which works as a link and I would like to give it an effect on hover. For example its background colour changes to orange.  Can I do it by CSS?

Or any other effect, such as an orange shadow around the shape inside the png image, and not the whole image (including transparent areas).

```
This is the code so far:

.latestTrack img {
    float:right;
    margin-right:50px !important;
}
.latestTrack img:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px orange; 
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a shadow around a shape of a png alpha image with a drop shadow filter.

```
-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(10px 10px 10px gray);
```

See this link for + info

[drop shadow filter comparison](http://demosthenes.info/blog/598/boxshadow-property-vs-dropshadow-filter-a-complete-comparison)